# Spring 3 Hibernate 4 SessionFactory is null

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I have a very simple app started and I can't seem to get the sessionFactory bean created or at least get access to it.  As you can see I have my web.xml, my root-context.xml and a dao.  When the dao is accessed, the sessionFactory is null.  Everthing is working bu that at this point.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

    xsi:schemaLocation=
        "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.acts542.mygunshop.*" />

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.acts542.mygunshop.controller.SecurityInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors> 

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mygunshop"/>
        <property name="username" value="mygunshop"/>
        <property name="password" value="sen32164"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>com.acts542.mygunshop.model</value>
                <value>com.acts542.mygunshop.dao</value>
                <value>com.acts542.mygunshop.service</value>
                <value>com.acts542.mygunshop.controller</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>

    package com.acts542.mygunshop.dao;

    // Generated Sep 12, 2013 11:27:13 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
    import org.hibernate.LockMode;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import com.acts542.mygunshop.model.Employees;

    import static org.hibernate.criterion.Example.create;

    /**
     * Home object for domain model class Employees.
     * @see com.acts542.mygunshop.model.Employees
     * @author Hibernate Tools
     */
    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class EmployeesHome
    {

        private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(EmployeesHome.class);

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) 
        {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

        public Session getSession() 
        {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }

        public void persist(Employees transientInstance)
        {
            log.debug("persisting Employees instance");
            try
            {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(transientInstance);
                log.debug("persist successful");
            }
            catch (RuntimeException re)
            {
                log.error("persist failed", re);
                throw re;
            }
        }

        public void attachDirty(Employees instance)
        {
            log.debug("attaching dirty Employees instance");
            try
            {
                this.getSession().saveOrUpdate(instance);
                log.debug("attach successful");
            }
            catch (RuntimeException re)
            {
                log.error("attach failed", re);
                throw re;
            }
        }

        public void attachClean(Employees instance)
        {
            log.debug("attaching clean Employees instance");
            try
            {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().lock(instance, LockMode.NONE);
                log.debug("attach successful");
            }
            catch (RuntimeException re)
            {
                log.error("attach failed", re);
                throw re;
            }
        }

        public void delete(Employees persistentInstance)
        {
            log.debug("deleting Employees instance");
            try
            {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(persistentInstance);
                log.debug("delete successful");
            }
            catch (RuntimeException re)
            {
                log.error("delete failed", re);
                throw re;
            }
        }

        public Employees merge(Employees detachedInstance)
        {
            log.debug("merging Employees instance");
            try
            {
                Employees result = (Employees) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(detachedInstance);
                log.debug("merge successful");
                return result;
            }
            catch (RuntimeException re)
            {
                log.error("merge failed", re);
                throw re;
            }
        }

        public Employees findById(java.lang.String id)
        {
            log.debug("getting Employees instance with id: " + id);
            try
            {
                Employees instance = (Employees) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(
                    "com.acts542.mygunshop.dao.Employees", id);
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    log.debug("get successful, no instance found");
                }
                else
                {
                    log.debug("get successful, instance found");
                }
                return instance;
            }
            catch (RuntimeException re)
            {
                log.error("get failed", re);
                throw re;
            }
        }

        public List<Employees> findByExample(Employees instance)
        {
            log.debug("finding Employees instance by example");
            try
            {
                List<Employees> results = (List<Employees>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createCriteria("com.acts542.mygunshop.dao.Employees").add(create(instance)).list();
                log.debug("find by example successful, result size: " + results.size());
                return results;
            }
            catch (RuntimeException re)
            {
                log.error("find by example failed", re);
                throw re;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have been at this all day.  Tried every example.  What am I missing

Comment: I think component-scan base-package should be "com.acts542.mygunshop", no dot, no star.

Comment: Can you share applicationContext.xml or Spring configuration?

Comment: `<context:annotation-config />` is already implied by `<context:component-scan />` as well as the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. Post the code that is using the repository (my guess is that you are constructing a new instance instead of using the one from the `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: I removed the non-needed tags.  I didn't seperate the code in my pot.  It has the DAO at the bottom.  As for applicationContext or Spring config, all I have is what is showing, which is a root-context.xml

Comment: IT'S Working - thanks for the info - really helps when you read the whole manual